# How can I rerender parent component if child component changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am developing a book tracker app which tracks books that you have read or is going to read. I am using Vue.js and Express.js on server side. There are three lists (categories). I am trying to apply functionality where button changes category of a book (i.e. from 'currently reading' to 'finished'). It works. But I have to reload whole page to see results. 
So I have a component 'my books' which includes component 'book list' where I pass 'listType' as a prop and render all three lists. In the 'book list' component I have v-for that renders all books and uses 'book' component for that and book object as a prop. And 'book' component has buttons for changing category. So when I press one of those buttons, I can change listType and update database entry on server side and even rerender the 'book' component, but I can not get to the point where my book moves from one list to another without refreshing the whole page.

//mybooks component

```
<template> 
   <BookList listType="current" />
   <BookList listType="wantToRead" />
   <BookList listType="finished" />
</template>
```

//booklist component

```
<template> 
    <div v-for="bookElement in bookList" :key="bookElement.id">
      <Book :book="bookElement" />
    </div>
</template>

<script> 
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      bookList: []
    };
  },
  components: {
    Book
  },
  props: ["listType"],
  watch: {
    "$route.query.searchDB": {
      //once a query string search value changes, get list of books from server
      immediate: true,
      async handler(value) {
        const list = (await BooksService.index(value)).data;

        //filter books by categories
        this.bookList = list.filter(element => {
          return element.listType === this.listType;
        });
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

// book component

```
//template to render author, title etc
//and button for example
<button @click="changeTo('current', book.id)">Change to current</button>

<script>
import BooksService from "@/services/BooksService";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isCurrent: false,
      isLater: false,
      isFinished: false
    };
  },
  props: ["book"],
  mounted() {
    if (this.book.listType === "current") {
      this.isCurrent = true;
    } else if (this.book.listType === "finished") {
      this.isFinished = true;
    } else this.isLater = true;
  },
  methods: {

    async changeTo(list) {
      this.book.listType = list;

      try {
        await BooksService.put(this.book);
      } catch (err) {
        this.error = err;
      }      
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Typically, if you want logic from a child component to affect a parent component then you need to move that logic up to the parent component. You'd then pass a reference to it either as props or with an `emit`. Otherwise, your parent component won't be affected by what its children are doing even if the children's state changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track but your not understanding the way Vue wants data handled.

***What you are doing right***

Your parent `booklist` component passes data to child component `Book` via the prop v-bind `:book`

***What needs to happen Now***

When something changes in `Book` it needs to do an emit event such as  `$emit('bookChanged', book)` so that any parent components know that something happened in its child components and needs to react. So in my example your code would look like

```
<Book :book="bookElement" @bookChanged="RefreshMe_Method"  />
```

At this point the RefreshMe_Method could do one of several things, this easiet would be to simply update the data being passed to the Prop `:book` or another more brute force option is to call `this.$forceUpdate();` but I am sure just updating the data will automatically refresh the data like you want.

***How data is handled***

1. A Parent passes data to the child (think school lunch on first day).
2. The Child displays Data, mutates data (local copy and not the Prop), or does something special. (Throwing away the vegetables)
3. The child is so proud of this it wants to let everyone know so it `$emits()` a change.
4. All parents see this and can do what they want from this point. (Ground the child and pack only Brocolli)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it doesn't work. I do $emit in the Book component and BookList component catch it and use method, but this.$forceUpdate() doesn't change anything. Then I tried to do the same with BookList and MyBooks component ($emit and catch it) and try forceUpdate there, doesn't work as well...

Comment: @NikitaSkopin Are you assigning the data back so it updates the prop of the child? forceUpdate will only refresh the render, if the data is the same there wont be a change.

Comment: Yeah, I did it before using forceUpdate, but did it wrong way. So eventually I solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @NikitaSkopin if this answer helped you solve your problem please mark it as answered. Good luck coding!